# Python recurrent copy from folder work in linux but not in win systems

Tags: python, linux, windows, filesystems, copytree

In my project a icreate a function for copy folder in recurrent mode from a path to another like this:

```
def copytree(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None):
    for item in os.listdir(src):
        s = os.path.join(src, item)
        d = os.path.join(dst, item)
        if os.path.isdir(s):
            shutil.copytree(s, d, symlinks, ignore)
        else:
            shutil.copy2(s, d)
        for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(d):
            for filename in files:
                print("To->",os.path.join(root, filename))
```

if i run my code on a linux server all works done, but if i run on a windows one the function copy just the last file in original folder.

How can i make this function work for all filesystem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: instead of `os.path`, try using `ntpath`.

Comment: In Windows, `os.path` is `ntpath`, and in POSIX it's `posixpath`, and both implementations import common functions from `genericpath`.

Comment: I assume you're doing it this way to allow the `dst` directory to exist, and merge `src` into it. This should copy all of the files in `src` to `dst` via `shutil.copy2` and all directories via `shutil.copytree`. I don't see an issue. I tested that it works in Windows Python 3.6 with a source directory with 2 files and 2 directories each containing 2 files.